# how can i split a a request from an html form?

Tags: http, request

im trying to convert a time form in java so i can manipulate the result, i try all kind of SimpleDataFormat but i ever recive an error 500

```
<%
String time = request.getParameter("time");
String[] split = time.split(":");
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <form action="test.jsp">
                <label for="time">ora1</label>
                <input id="time" type="time" name="time"  value="00:00">
                <input type="submit" value="ok">
            </form>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijVDU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a `limit` in your split.  This is required.

For your application, I would use `0` since you are only separating 2 parameters.

```
String[] split = time.split(":", 0);
```

If you were to

```
for (String a : split)
    System.out.println(a);
```

This should give you:

```
00
00
```

Comment: i tryed this way but continue give me same error, i think the problem is when i try to split a request parameter.